# Поверхность вращения на основе кривой

Tags: python

Есть кривая - массив значений точек x,y,z

```
xvals=[0 0 0...]
yvals=[2 1 1...]
zvals=[1 1 1...]
```

Как построить любую поверхность вращения но основе этой кривой? Пробовал

```
x = np.arange (0, 0.1, 0.005)
y = np.arange (0, 2*np.pi, 0.005)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
x=xgrid
y=ygrid
z=zvals
fig = pylab.figure()
axes = Axes3D(fig)
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z)
```

Но получается совсем не то, что нужно. Где ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: Вокруг чего вращаем? Почему значения xvals и yvals никак не участвуют в построении поверхности?

Comment: @Эникейщик - учавствуют, смотри внимательно.

Comment: автор - полярные координаты в np должны быть)

Comment: @eri В какой строчке?

Comment: В 3. Там он это все кладет на сетку, а потом хочет крутануть целиком

Comment: В 3 строчке нет ``xvals`` и ``yvals``?

Comment: использовал только z=zvals (6 строчка). И если честно, то не понимаю как действовать дальше